# how to make Wait until all threads finished it's work from threadpool in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

```
for (int task = 0; task < 20; task++)
{

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(TaskCallBack), new object[] { filepath1, filepath2, 
                  filepath3 });

}

public static void TaskCallBack(object state)
{
            object[] array = state as object[];
            string filea = Convert.ToString(array[0]);
            string fileb = Convert.ToString(array[1]);
            string filec = Convert.ToString(array[2]);
            //something below         

}
```

I want main thread to be waited until all threads finishes its work. Please help

Comment: Either you could switch to use `Task.Run` together with `Task.WhenAll` and `await`, but this could leed to more changes in your code since `async await` spreads upward in the call chain (what is not bad, but maybe unwanted). Alternativly I would suggest taking a look  at the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_ThreadPool_QueueUserWorkItem_System_Threading_WaitCallback_System_Object_). They use an array of `ManualResetEvent` to message that the operation is complete.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this would be to use `Task.Run()` and `Task.WhenAll()`, or to use `Parallel.Invoke()`.

However, if you need to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` you can solve this issue as follows:

1. For ease of use, encapsulate all the data that you want to pass to the thread in a class. This data should include an instance of [`CountdownEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=netframework-4.8) initialised with a count equal to the number of threads you want to wait for. (In the sample code below, this class is called `ThreadData`.)
2. Inside your `TaskCallBack()` methods, call `CountdownEvent.Signal()` when the method has completed.
3. Inside the main thread, start all the threadpool threads and then call `CountdownEvent.Wait()` to wait for all the threads to complete.

Putting this all together in a compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace CoreConsole
{
    public sealed class ThreadData
    {
        public ThreadData(CountdownEvent countdown, int index)
        {
            Countdown = countdown;
            Index     = index;
        }

        public CountdownEvent Countdown { get; }
        public int Index { get; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int n = 20;
            var countdown  = new CountdownEvent(n);

            for (int task = 0; task < n; task++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(TaskCallBack, new ThreadData(countdown, task));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all threads to exit");

            countdown.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Waited for all threads to exit");
        }

        public static void TaskCallBack(object state)
        {
            var data = (ThreadData) state;

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {data.Index} is starting.");

            Thread.Sleep(_rng.Next(2000, 10000));
            data.Countdown.Signal();

            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {data.Index} has finished.");
        }

        static readonly Random _rng = new Random(45698);
    }
}
```

The `ThreadData.Index` property is just used to identify each thread in the `Console.WriteLine()` calls.

Note: In real code, it is important to always signal the `Countdown` event, even if the thread throws an exception - so you should wrap the code in a try/finally like so:

```
public static void TaskCallBack(object state)
{
    var data = (ThreadData)state;

    try
    {
        // Do work here.
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {data.Index} is starting.");
        Thread.Sleep(_rng.Next(2000, 10000));
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread {data.Index} has finished.");
    }

    finally
    {
        data.Countdown.Signal();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ackdari mentioned in his comment, you could use **Task.Run**. But you don't need the **await** keyword. Just create a collection with the tasks and wait for it.

Example:

```
// Create a list that will hold the tasks
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>;

// Create the tasks
for (int taskId = 0; taskId < 20; task++)
{
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { TaskCallBack(new object[] { filepath1, filepath2, filepath3 }); }));
}

// Wait for ALL tasks to complete
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

That way you could also use your own method that will be run by the task.
Example:

```
public static void ReplaceWithABetterName(string[] filePaths)
{
   string filea = filePaths[0);
   string fileb = filePaths[1];
   string filec = filePaths[2];
   //do stuff       
}
```